# Change Color of Element when Printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, printing

I am trying to print the my whole website, normally the background turns white which is good, but i cant get the background color of an element to change to white to save ink.

This is the code

```
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="900" height="700" id="Kirchhoff" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="Kirchoff.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<embed src="Kirchhoff.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#DDB85F" width="900" height="700" name="Kirchhoff" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque" />
<br>
```

and this it the print code so far

```
SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
if (window.print) {
document.write('<form> '
+ '<input type=button name=print value="Imprimir" '
+ 'onClick="javascript:window.print()"></form>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should do this with CSS, not JavaScript.

```
@media print{
  .element {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @JoshSpears i am kinda new to this and self taught, were do I input it. Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to create an external css file in your directory. For example `styles.css`;

then include it in your `head` tag of your html file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`

Comment: I am sorry if I am industrially wrong I just starting. I created a file with the previous code and named it styles.css and saved it in the same directory then i changed the code to this

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_multiple2

Comment: Yes just one question the file is just a normal plain text with the code you typed, with .css extension. Because i cant get it to work

Comment: it's not a plain text file, its a `css` file. Follow that tutorial link.

Comment: yes i mean a plain text named styles.css @JohnSpears

Comment: @JohnSpears also my problem is an elements background color not turning white not the websites color.

Answer (score 0):

@JoshSpears this would be the new one

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
<body bgcolor="#7CF8EC">
    <br>
    <br>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="900" height="700" id="Kirchhoff" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="Kirchoff.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
<embed src="Kirchhoff.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#DDB85F" width="900" height="700" name="Kirchhoff" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque" />
<br>
        <center><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
if (window.print) {
document.write('<form> '
+ '<input type=button name=print value="Imprimir" '
+ 'onClick="javascript:window.print()"></form>');
}
</script>
      </center>
</body>
</html>
```